# Error while making a Python API. Please have a look

Tags: python, api

https://github.com/ashwinidotx/RIOTGames-API/issues/1

I was trying to create a League of Legends API to get summoner information but I got an error related to the URL. please have a look

here's the error:

```
  $ python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 9, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 5, in main
    r=api.get_summoner_by_name('shadyjoker27')
  File "/Users/macdonald/Developer/TwitterBot/RiotSumm.py", line 31, in get_summoner_by_name
    return self._request(api_url)
  File "/Users/macdonald/Developer/TwitterBot/RiotSumm.py", line 21, in _request
    params=args
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 72, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 618, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 508, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='euw.api.pvp.net', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/lol/euw/v1.4/summoner/by-name/shadyjoker27?api_key=RGAPI-3b0be3d6-1f3c-4e6f-9e52-9d9904af2c21 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x107698a50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known',))
```

Comment: https://discussion.developer.riotgames.com/questions/2210/python-connection-error-httpsconnectionpool.html

Answer (score 0):

You are connecting to `euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.4/summoner/by-name/shadyjoker27?api_key=RGAPI-3b0be3d6-1f3c-4e6f-9e52-9d9904af2c21` via HTTPS. The error message is telling you that this connection does not exist on HTTPS. Open your browser and go to: https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.4/summoner/by-name/shadyjoker27?api_key=RGAPI-3b0be3d6-1f3c-4e6f-9e52-9d9904af2c21. You will find that no such connection exists. Before you make any http requests in python, try them in your browser, because if they don't work their, they wont be working in python. In this case the connection you are trying to make might not be available via HTTPS. Try simply making the connection to `euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.4/summoner/by-name/shadyjoker27?api_key=RGAPI-3b0be3d6-1f3c-4e6f-9e52-9d9904af2c21`.